# wxWidgets and "Implement_App" causes _main duplicate symbol error

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, linker-errors

I'm compiling a trivial wxWidgets app on MacOS X 10.6 with XCode 3.2

The linker is return an error about the symbol `_main` being defined twice:

- once in main.mm
- once in the test_app.cpp file.

After I commented out the macro:

```
Implement_App(TestApp)
```

The error went away, compiled & linked and I was able to run the application.

I haven't found this anywhere so any ideas about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IMPLEMENT_APP` is a macro used in wxWidgets to create an entry point to the program without worrying about whether the program will be compiled on Windows, Mac, *nix, or whatever.  As a result of this, `IMPLEMENT_APP` *has* to define `main` (or its equivalent, such as `WinMain`).

You might find the [`IMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN` macro](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxWidgets/trunk/include/wx/app.h?rev=61886#L808) to be useful.  Check the other `IMPLEMENT_APP_XXX` functions in wx/app.h, too.

This paragraph from [the wxApp overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxappoverview.html) is a little helpful too:

> Note the use of IMPLEMENT_APP(appClass), which allows wxWidgets to dynamically create an instance of the application object at the appropriate point in wxWidgets initialization. Previous versions of wxWidgets used to rely on the creation of a global application object, but this is no longer recommended, because required global initialization may not have been performed at application object construction time.